# Choosing number of instances in Google Cloud Run

Tags: php, nginx, load-testing, google-cloud-run

I am running a PHP-FPM application inside Google Cloud Run connected to a Cloud SQL database. My application is running fine in normal use, but we sometimes release a large amount of products, and expect a high traffic load. We know in advance when our customers release their products and the traffic will increase, so we are able to plan our server capacity accordingly.

We are expecting about 1000 customers, who will refresh the page like crazy. That will generate a lot of pressure on our database, as many of the endpoints generate a huge amount of queries to the database.
I have been running [Siege](https://www.joedog.org/siege-manual/) to load test my application, and I therefore know that our database is the critical point when the server load increases. Normally we run on only one Cloud Run instance. I also know from earlier test runs with Siege, that much traffic causes Cloud Run to spin up new instances on the fly. This was a very time consuming process for our application, resulting in a high average request processing time. For this reason, we want to have more than 1 container instance ready for the release.
For earlier, and smaller, releases, we have bumped the minimum number of containers to 20, but that number is taken pretty much out of the blue.
Therefore I am looking for the optimal setup to run in Cloud Run for these releases, but
I am struggling to find any good answers to how many Cloud Run instances I should run, both "min servers" and "max servers".

These are my relevant application configs:

Cloud Run configs:

```
8 GB RAM
4 CPUs
Maximum requests per container: 80
```

Database configs:

```
15 GB RAM
4 CPUs
EDIT: Can handle 4000 simultaneous connections
```

Relevant PHP-FPM configs:

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 375 (formula: (8000MB - 500MB)/ 20MB. Memory of server minus some "extras", limited to 20 MB per child.)
pm.start_servers = 37 (formula: 10% of pm.max_children)
pm.min_spare_servers = 35 (Bit of a guess, must be less than pm.start_servers.
pm.max_spare_servers = 100 (Bit of a guess on my side)
```

So my Cloud Run instance is accepting a total of 80 parallel requests, and my PHP-FPM allows 375 child processes.

I have seen in [Cloud Run concurrency docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling) that "...when you set a maximum instances limit, in some scenarios there will be insufficient instances to meet that traffic load. In that case, incoming requests can be queued for up to 10 seconds".
It is important to us not dropping any requests, so I can not have too few instances running either.

My questions:

- Is there any formula involving number of processes, server hardware or any of the abovementioned specs that could point me to an ideal number of instances in Cloud Run?
- Should I limit the max number of containers that Cloud Run can spin up? I am pretty confident that 100 Cloud Run containers all spamming my database simultaneously will lead to disaster.
- Could it be a good idea to implement a separate queuing functionality outside of my application, so that it is not overloaded?
- Could anyone point me to some other resources that can get me in the right direction here? The only proper thing I have been able to find is a course on Pluralsight, [High Performance PHP](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/php-highly-performant), but it does not cover running and scaling your application in the cloud.

I understand that the answers to these questions are not completely black and white, but I am looking for some guidelines, as I don't find the Cloud Run docs especially enlightening. I don't know whether I should use 2 or 20 containers in the future.

PS: This upscaling is for a very limited time only, so I don't care about the cost of running many containers. I simply want the best performance with the least chance of disaster.

Comment: You can refer to this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/general) for the best practices and recommendations in designing, implementing, testing and deploying a Cloud Run service. @larsesen

Comment: Hi @CatherineO I have seen this page as well, but it does no go into any detail on choosing the number of instances.

Answer (score 1):

Advanced topics like that required tests, deep analysis and good knowledge of all the element of your infrastructure. Anyway, I will try to answer some keypoints.

Firstly, I don't know any formula to know the correct number of instance of Cloud Run.

The power of Cloud Run is the capacity to scale up and down automatically. However, I understand that a container start is very long and you prefer avoid that feature to keep the request latency low (note that the cold start occur only once and then your queries are served fast, so the impact is minimal considering the volume of request that you have (i.e. in percentage), but I can understand your use case).

To solve that issue, you can set a min number of instance. Those instances are started and kept warm. You don't have to start them to serve traffic. However, you will pay 10% of the CPU cost and 100% of the memory cost of a standard instance serving traffic.

How many instances to set? It's not a Cloud Run question but a database question: How many connections one Cloud Run instance can create with the database? And how many connections can accept the database? And of course, how many query can be performed on your database without crashing it (you can also think about read replicas to solve some challenges)

You also have to monitor the Cloud Run instances to be sure to always have enough capacity no to drop any request. Cloud Run can also queue automatically the request up to 10 seconds, no need to add an external layer for that.

*My answer is not perfect, but can help you to go quicker to the right choice.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I forgot to write that my database can handle 4000 simultaneous connections, I will update my question with that now. But am I comparing these 4000 connections to 80 requests from Cloud Run, or the 375 children in my PHP?

I will definitely have a look at read replicas, as that sounds like a perfect way to take some load off the main database.

What I am afraid of with the 10 seconds queuing, is if the database really clogs up, then a lot of requests will be lost.